# Simpler solution to find changes in lists with dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for a better and simpler solution to find changes between two nested lists within dicts, archived and actual data.

I want to find:

- added data in actual data
- deleted data from actual data
- changes inside data -search by `id` values (unique number for data)

`self.l_dicts_arch` - archived data

`self.l_dicts_actual` - actual data

Here's my function:

```
def check(self):
    for item in self.l_dicts_arch: 
        if item in self.l_dicts_actual:#remove correct data
            self.l_dicts_actual.remove(item) 
        elif item not in l_dicts_actual:
            for item2 in l_dicts_actual:
                if item['id']==item2['id']:#display and remove data with error
                    print 'Found error in data'
                    print 'from first list', item
                    print 'from second list',item2
                    actual_list.remove(item2)
                else:
                    print 'This item was removed from actual list'#display deleted data
                    print item
    if len(self.l_dicts_actual)!=0:
        print 'This item was added on actual list'
        for item in self.l_dicts_actual:
            print item
```

Comment: Maybe better for CodeReview ?

Comment: There are some nice solutions over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755376/getting-the-difference-delta-between-two-lists-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following sets :

`actual = [{'id' : 4, 'data' : 'foo'}, {'id' : 5, 'data' : 'toto'}, {'id' : 7, 'data' : 'tagada'}]
arch = [{'id' : 4, 'data' : 'foo'}, {'id' : 5, 'data' : 'toto2'},  {'id' : 6, 'data' : 'tata'}]`

Here are some solutions :

- Items deleted (finding on 'id' tag) :

`deleted = filter(lambda x: not x['id'] in map(lambda x: x['id'], actual), arch)`

- Added data (finding on 'id' tag) :

`added = filter(lambda x: not x['id'] in map(lambda x: x['id'], arch), actual)`

- Modified items :

`modified = filter(lambda x: not x in arch, filter(lambda x: x['id'] in map(lambda x: x['id'], arch), actual))`

A cool code could be something like this :

`def check(arch, actual):
    id_actual = map(lambda x: x['id'], actual)
    id_arch = map(lambda x: x['id'], arch)
    deleted = filter(lambda x: not x['id'] in id_actual, arch)
    added = filter(lambda x: not x['id'] in id_arch, actual)
    modified = filter(lambda x: not x in arch, filter(lambda x: x['id'] in id_arch, actual))`

EDIT: I think you can optimize that, I'm looking for another solution...

Comment: Thanks Guy, your solution really help me now, but if you find some better, paste here :-)

Comment: I think that you can patch something in this code : if you know that few elements of your list will be modified, you can add at the top of check function something like this :

`actual, arch = filter(lambda x: x not in arch, actual), filter(lambda x: x not in actual, arch)`

That will reduce a lot of treatments. I'm looking for something else too.

Comment: I'm also a fanboy of `filter`, `map` and `lambda`, but you also can do it with easier list declaration i think...